# how to setup a SVN server with collabnet subversion edge on windows server, and how to connect to it remotely using Xcode on Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, svn, collabnet, svn-server

I am a newbie about SVN server. I've certainly used SVN to check in/out codes before, but never learned how to setup a Subversion server it up from ground up.

What I have:

**Server | Windows Server 2012 Standard, Activated:**

- Installed Collabnet Subversion Edge,
- Created a repository,
- Created users and also started the server, using start button at GUI on `localhost:4434/csvn/`.

**Client | MacOSX Mountain, with Xcode 4.5 Installed:**

I have tried to add repository by using the external IP address and the repository name
like `https://1.1.1.1/svn/`, but as expected, it does not work and says *"Host is unreachable"*.

I have tried to use the local hostname, no luck either. Although I did notice in their documentation, they mentioned IP address setting, but I cannot find it anywhere.

I would like to make it so that users can access and use the SVN repository remotely and locally.

I have no idea what to do, please help me. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have sloved the problem. I knew I have to access the repo using my external IP address somehow, but when I tried something like, for example my IP is 1.1.1.1, when I typeed `https://1.1.1.1/svn/reposname`, I got a no response message.

I figured that since there are more than 1 computers on my local network, the router has to somehow direct the request to my server only, not some other machine. After some reaserch I found that port forwarding does the trick. Since apache server uses port 80 as default, just get the default gateway ip using ipconfig from CMD, then enable port forwarding for port 80, to the server's local ip address. At least I can access it using my external ip on my local network. I will try to access it remotely and see.

Answer (score 2):

Go back to the server for a minute.  When you are configuring it, are you only using the local web browser?  Have you tried accessing the server using web browser from your Mac?  I would see if the Mac can reach the web gui first.  Maybe you have network issues you have to resolve, such as DNS, routing or firewall.

In terms of using XCode, or any SVN Client, the URL you must enter is the URL to your repository. That will not be:

`https://1.1.1.1/svn/`

It will be something like:

`https://1.1.1.1/svn/reposname`

In the Subversion Edge web GUI if you go to the list of repositories, you will see an example checkout command next to each repository.  This command shows you the URL to enter in a SVN client to reach the root of the repository.  Example screenshot here:

https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/projects/svnedge/screenshots/screens/repos/repos.png

Comment: Thanks. So I've got the repository working locally by disabling my windows firewall on the server. My server name is say SVN-SERVER, can a user access the repository remotely? Is it by going to "https://SVN-SERVER/svn/reposname"? Do you have to use their cloud service in order to make a repository that is accessible remotely?